# How can I install ExtUtils::PkgConfig in Perl on Windows?

Tags: windows, perl, cpan, pkg-config

I've tried cpan and cpanp shell and I keep getting:

```
ExtUtils::PkgConfig requires the pkg-config utility, but it doesn't
seem to be in your PATH.  Is it correctly installed?
```

What is the pkg-config utility and how do I install it?

Updates:

- OS: Windows
- This module is a prerequisite for the File::Extractor module

Comment: What distribution are you using? Are you on Linux, BSD or something else? Have you tried running "whereis pkg-config"?

Comment: on Windows ... trying to find a binary ...

Answer (score 6):

look here:
http://gtk2-perl.sourceforge.net/win32/howto_build_gtk2perl_win32.html
I found this page by googling for ExtUtils::PkgConfig and "PPM" (Actvestates Perl Package Manager).

Answer (score 4):

pkg-config is used for when you are compiling applcations and libraries.  It's really used for inserting the right command line arguments.

It comes installed on most new releases of linux, but is pretty common if it's not there initially so it shouldn't be too hard to find.

Here's how to install it on ubuntu:

```
 sudo apt-get install pkg-config
```

Here's the wikipedia page:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pkg-config

Answer (score 3):

http://pkgconfig.freedesktop.org/wiki/

pkg-config is a helper tool used when compiling applications and libraries.
Depending on your OS, you might be able to get a binary distribution (try apt-get on Ubuntu, for example), otherwise you can get the source from their web site.

Answer (score 3):

I found the Windows binaries for the pkg-config utility here: 
http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/binaries/win32/dependencies/

(Link was found here: http://www.go-evolution.org/Building_Evolution_on_Windows)

Update: straight download link from [gtk.org](http://www.gtk.org/download-windows.html) : [pkg-config-0.23-2.zip](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/binaries/win32/dependencies/pkg-config-0.23-2.zip)

Thanks for the pointers!

Answer (score 0):

A better source for Windows binaries for pkg-config is [the gtk site](http://www.gtk.org/download/win64.php)